# How can I make the AdView always be below a WebView OR on the bottom of the display (which ever one is higher up)?

Tags: android, webview, android-relativelayout

I've got a relative layout with an Admob AdView aligned to the bottom and then a WebView that is specified to be right above the AdView.

```
<RelativeLayout>
<WebView>
<AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This works fine, but if the WebView's height is less than (phone's screen height - AdView height), the webview is not aligned to the top of the phone's display. For example, if the webview contains a single line of text, the line of text will be near the bottom of the phone, right above the AdView.

What I want is:
1. if the WebView's height is less than (screen height - AdView height), AdView is right below the webView
2. if the WebView's height is greater or equal to (screen height - AdView height), AdView is at bottom of screen. When the WebView is scrolled to the bottom, the bottom of the webview should be viewable and not concealed by the AdView.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your `AdView`. Recent blog about this: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/12/incorporating-android-admob-ads-into.html